# MapStruct: trouble with abstract class

Tags: java, class, abstract, mapstruct

I have some trouble with MapStruct using abstract class.
I have 2 mappers:

```
MapperA extends AbstractMapper<U,V>
MapperB extends AbstractMapper<U,V>
```

MapperA uses MapperB

I have a method in `AbstractMapper`

```
public <T extends AbstractReference> T resolveReference(String id, @TargetType Class<T> entityClass) {
    // Some implementation
}
```

While clean install, i got the ambiguous method error.

It seems that Mapstruct find the method twice, one frome each Mapper that extends the same class.

I did some search on the qualifier thing but it seems usefull when using different methods with the same signature. But in my case, it's the same one!!

If you have any ints.

Thanks

Edit:

```
    @Mapper(componentModel = "cdi", uses = {MapperB.class}) 
    @ApplicationScoped 
    public abstract class MapperA extends AbstractMapper<U1,V1> {}
```

MapperB does not use any other mapper.

```
    @Mapper(componentModel = "cdi")
    @ApplicationScoped
    public abstract class MapperB extends AbstractMapper<U2,V2> {}
```

Comment: Can you show use your mapper definitions? Are you maybe using `MapperA` in `MapperB` or opposite?

Comment: @Mapper(componentModel = "cdi", uses = {MapperB.class})
        @ApplicationScoped
public abstract class MapperA extends AbstractMapper<U,V> {} MapperB does not use any other mapper.

Comment: Why is it that you have those type parameters declared on your mappers? Where are they used?

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually have one method, you have 2 methods. One in `MapperA` and another one in `MapperB`. MapStruct does not care about the inheritance and where each method is located.

Also your method

```
public <T extends AbstractReference> T resolveReference(String id, @TargetType Class<T> entityClass) {
    // Some implementation
}
```

is a generic one that has the same erasure and does not depend on the `AbstractMapper` generic parameters, which leads to the ambiguous method error by MapStruct.

I am not sure what you are actually doing in the method. But if it is something generic that does not depend on the `AbstractMapper` generic parameters `U` and `V`, then I would suggest that you extract this method to a different class and add that class to the `uses` annotation variable.

If the method is dependent on the parameters then make sure that they are part of it, then MapStruct will work correctly as they would have a different type during compilation (`U1, V1` or `U2, V2`)

Comment: I think you are write, i should use a different class with the uses annotation (Lets call it MapperUtil). But the problem will remain the same if MapperA and MapperB use the MapperUtil class, the method will still appear twice.

Comment: No it won't, if you use the MapperUtill class then MapStruct will know that it comes from the same class and it should not be a problem. See the comment from @gunnar on your question as well. If you use the types in the `resolveReference` then it should work as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works with the MapperUtil class :)

Comment: That is great. If it worked you can accept my answer maybe